# Display Suite Extra Fields not showing in content page

Tags: 8, display-suite

Display suite extra fields are shown in the manage display.  Fields such as author, user, AND submitted by, are enabled in the custom regions I have defined using a custom ds layout.  When I go to the full content page it does not show any of the extra ds fields that i enabled.  Does anybody know what the issue can be?

I'm using a custom ds layout

```
custom_article:
  label: article
  category: My Layouts
  template: templates/custom_article
  css: css/custom-article.css
  regions:
    header:
      label: header
    author:
      label: author
    body:
      label: body
```

Comment: You need to select your custom layout in full view content

Comment: It is already selected for the full view content @ShreyaShetty

Comment: Is your custom layout getting rendered ??

Comment: Thats the weird thing I'm not too sure.  Like the regions from the layout are shown in manage display and when I put fields into regions they go on the page where they belong but when i inspect it using twig debug I don't see any of the custom html that wrote in the twig file for the layout. @ShreyaShetty

Comment: using drush command did you create ds template

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding a class key, for example:

```
class: '\Drupal\ds\Plugin\DsLayout'
```

Also, I think you should update the template line, replace the underscore with a hyphen (and do the same for the actual twig file), for example:

```
template: templates/custom-article
```